# PHP regex to remove last matching pattern string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have following URLs

```
http://domain.com/baby/smile/love/index.txt
http://domain.com/baby/smile/love/toy.txt
http://domain.com/baby/smile/love/car.html
and so on...
```

using preg regex, how to remove the file name on the right? I guess it's required to match the first dash starting from the right, how I can do this?

So for example if I run something like

`$newUrl = preg_match('xxxxxx', '', $url);`

or using

```
$newURL = preg_replace(...);
```

The $newUrl variable will only contain

```
http://domain.com/baby/smile/love/
```

preserving the trailing slash at the end. I was able to do it by using explode(), array_pop(), then implode() to put it back together, just wondering if it 's possible using only regex.

Thank you.

Comment: If you need regex free solution , try this `echo substr($link1,0,strrpos($link1,'/')+1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following.

```
function clean($url) {
   $link = substr(strrchr($url, '/'), 1);
   return substr($url, 0, - strlen($link));
}

echo clean($url);
```

See [`Live demo`](https://eval.in/75777)

Using regular expression:

```
$newUrl = preg_replace('~[^/]*$~', '', $url);
```

See [`Live demo`](https://eval.in/75762)

Comment: Thank you so much, this preg_replace is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$str = 'http://domain.com/baby/smile/love/index.txt';

$str = preg_replace('/(.*\/).*/', '$1', $str);
print $str;
```

Output:

```
http://domain.com/baby/smile/love/
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$s = 'http://domain.com/baby/smile/love/index.txt';

if (preg_match_all('~^.+?/(?!.*?/)~', $s, $matches))
        print_r ( $matches[0] );
```

#### OUTPU:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://domain.com/baby/smile/love/
)
```